# Displaying tool tip for dropdown list items in Infopath 2010

Tags: infopath

I need to display a tooltip for Dropdown List items in Infopath Form 2010 as my text is getting truncated, the drop-down list is bound to an external data connection.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to truncate list items, but when the user moves over the *item* it displays a tooltip.  As opposed to setting the Accessible Field to the dropdown?

Comment: Russel I need to display dropdown items in tool tip when the user moves over the item.

Comment: Yeah, that is certainly a significant customisation of the control.  Certainly not out of the box or easily configurable.

Comment: Can't you just make the size of the control larger so the options aren't truncated?

Comment: Eric , Actually I am migrating Lotus notes forms to SharePoint Infopath Forms 2010 so changing Layout will change look and feel of the form and also the dropdowns items are quiet lengthy.